# org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties timeouts don't work on WildFly

Tags: java, timeout, jax-rs, wildfly

I've got the following code for HTTP timeouts support:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    WebTarget target = client.target(url);
    Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(null, Response.class);
```

It works fine for standalone java application. It  waits 1000ms for the response, then `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` occurs.

I need to use this code on WildFly 8.2.0. The problem is that after 1000ms of waiting nothing happens. This code waits for infinite time. I guess that `ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and `ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT` are not suitable for WildFly. Probably I have to use other constants. Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClientProperties is a jersey specific class, its properties are jersey specific.  Wildfly uses RestEasy as its JAX-RS provider.

You can configure the underlying Apache HttpClient here: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.17.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html

To configure timeout in HttpClient: https://www.jayway.com/2009/03/17/configuring-timeout-with-apache-httpclient-40/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I have to rewrite the whole code (for http requests) and change the dependencies due to the ClientProperties constants? (In spite of the fact that http requests are executed correctly). Seems a little bit strange:(

Comment: Well, you're leveraging impl specific behavior.  I usually create a producer method and wire in clients that way.  This way it only touches a single point.